# Django model form mutiple selector can not save inti DB

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I have a question as below. I stuck in this problem for a while.

I build up an order in django model form which provide customer using shopping cart to fill their transaction info.

Below is my code structure :

```
## models.py
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

```
## forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Order
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout,Div,Field
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 'postal_code','city']
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper = Layout(
            Div(Field('city') , id="twzipcode_ADV"),
        )
```

```
## views.py

from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from .models import OrderItem

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
```

```
## .html
    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field is form.city or field is form.county%}
              <div id="twzipcode_ADV"></div>
            {% else %}
              {{field.name}}
              {{field}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% buttons %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-product">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Place order
            </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-twzipcode@1.7.14/jquery.twzipcode.min.js'></script>
 <script src="{%static "js/orders/create.js" %}"></script>
```

```
## create.js
$("#twzipcode_ADV").twzipcode({
zipcodeIntoDistrict: true, 
css: ["city form-control", "town form-control"], 
countyName: "city", 
districtName: "town" 
});
```

And the website can be shown as figure below .
As I show in the red rectangular area. My question is when I press down the placeholder button,the second selector will not be saved into city field I have already defined in models.py . However it only store the first selector. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: figure is here:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbmJL.png

Comment: Your checkout form is showing two selector with choices of data.How you did this?  But your models shows only 'city' after 'postal_code'. it shows one field but in your figure it shows two fields. And what you want exactly here?

Comment: https://github.com/Chris-Tsai/zipcode-tw-react

Comment: I use the the above JavaScript API packaged in the Jason form to achieve two selector in one div tag and you can see in js file.Further more you can refer the above URL for more details. I want both of them however I just can extract the first one.

Comment: https://codepen.io/minwt/pen/PoYZyGb

Comment: You can also refer to this URL

Comment: `OrderCreateForm` this is your form.  and your model field `fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 'postal_code','city']` SO there is no `country` field in here. but you want to save the city and country simultaneously. so in your model you need to create 'country' field since you want to save country field value also.  In forms.py file `{% if field is form.city or field is form.county%}` i think  `form.country` is not showing anything since its not defined in the model field.

Comment: I have tried the method you mention . It,s doesnt work.

Comment: You want to save: 1) city 2) country or only city?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add extra field value which comes dynamically as a form value then you may add it in views.py:

```
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from .models import OrderItem

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            country = form.cleaned_data.get("country")
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.country = country
            order.save()
```

Your model must have this field in the field list. And need to make the migration. Otherwise field value will not be saved rather it will triggered the error.